# TextButton does not receive clicks in LibGDX

Tags: libgdx

Here is my code:

```
public WelcomeScreen(final WallGame game) {
    this.game = game;
    // Setting up camera and viewport.
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    viewport = new StretchViewport(GAME_WORLD_WIDTH, GAME_WORLD_HEIGHT, camera);
    viewport.apply();
    stage = new Stage(viewport);
    camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2, camera.viewportHeight / 2, 0);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("uiskin.json"));
    skin.getFont("default-font").getData().setScale(0.1f, 0.1f);

    backgroundTxtr = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("background/background.png"));
    background = new Image(backgroundTxtr);
    background.setBounds(0, 0, GAME_WORLD_WIDTH, GAME_WORLD_HEIGHT);

    final TextButton button = new TextButton("start", skin, "red-button");
    button.setBounds(10, 10, 50, 50);
    button.setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);
    button.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            Gdx.app.log("AKS", "CLICKED");
        }
    });

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog("Click Message", skin);
    dialog.setBounds(50, 50, 40, 40);

    stage.addActor(background);
    stage.addActor(button);
    stage.addActor(dialog);

}
```

I can't seem to make the button work, I have an image to be shown when the button is clicked (the "down" attribute of the `TextButton`) but it doesn't change. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. I hadn't created a `Table` object to add the button into. It worked after I did that.

Comment: A table should not be nececary for a button to function.

Comment: You certainly don't need a table to have a button. Something else must have been wrong.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I just removed the table and it still works. I am not sure what the problem was then.